# Facebook Post Hyperlink Appears Plain Text

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, server-side

I have the following code snippet to post on facebook wall. But when I post hyperlink, appears plain text.

```
public static bool WriteOnFace(string message, string accessToken)
    {
            string url= "";
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            url= "https://graph.facebook.com/feed?access_token=" + accessToken + "&message=" + message + "&method=post";
            wc.DownloadString(url);
    }
```

**I'm not using facebook C# sdk. How to Post Hyperlink?**

Comment: Using the `link` parameter – see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts

Answer (score 0):

Try using Facebook C# sdk and instantiating a FacebookClient with your access token and then calling the postasync method on it with a link parameter. Something along these lines should work:

```
FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient('use your access token');
var args = new Dictionary<string, object>();
args["link"] = "[your link URL]";
client.PostAsync("friend's id/feed",args);
```

Hope this helps!